# Dúvida de otimização

Tags: javascript, html5

Fala galera, beleza ?

Tenho uma duvida... Estou fazendo um sistema que contem varias telas , e eu estou organizando da seguinte maneira , eu criei um único index para a pagina principal, e nesse index tem todo o conteúdo das telas , meus `forms`  , logicamente organizado dentro dos padrões do `HTML5`. E para cada tela eu tenho um arquivo `.js`. Minha duvida é , agrupar todo esse conteudo de dentro de um unico`index html`  prejudica a renderização e a otimização do meu sistema ?

Obrigado!

Comment: Não necessariamente. Se normalmente a aplicação vai ser acessada por quem usa várias telas, não vejo problema. O problema de se carregar coisa a mais é evidente num site acessado por uma quantidade grande de pessoas. Se for um sistema utilizado num ambiente com 200 pessoas, a carga a mais não vai fazer diferença significativa. E tem o cache! Melhor priorizar a organização do que a separação num caso desses. A questão é: qual seria o ganho juntando tudo? O que precisa fazer é colocar os benefícios de cada opção na balança. Só pelo que foi descrito na pergunta, não tem resposta "única e certa".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vou tentar complementar um pouco a outra resposta.

Sim, você pode acabar prejudicando o desempenho, mas vale levar em consideração o tipo de página / app que você está criando.

Se for uma página simples que pode ser usada em dispositivos móveis (3G ou 4G) o peso é de extrema importância, já que o app pode estar sendo executado em uma rede de baixa velocidade, alta latência e até possivelmente em um dispositivo com pouquissimos recursos de ram, etc.

Então, deixar sua página pesada irá certamente prejudicar a experiência nestes casos, mas se for uma página para ser usada primariamente (ou exclusivamente) em desktops (ex: um sistema web) onde as pessoas tendem a ficar muito tempo online na ferramenta, vale a pena demorar um pouco mais para carregar na abertura e depois ter uma experiência suave durante o uso.

Coisas a levar em consideração:
1) Quanto mais arquivos separados, maior a chance de serem disparadas várias requisições para seu servidor o que, com alta latência, causará lentidão no carregamento. Com o http/2 isso pode passar a ser irrelevante.
2) QUanto maiores os seus arquivos, mais tempo levará para serem carregados, mas se você configurar os headers corretamente para cache, terá usuários baixando o arquivo apenas uma vez e depois recebendo o 304 como retorno (not modified / não modificado). Isso ajudará muito as próximas vezes que o usuário entrar na página
3) Mesmo que opte por deixar tudo em um único arquivo, dê uma olhada no "peso" do seu site (em kb mesmo) e tente levar em consideração o perfil de pessoas que irão utilizar. Se forem em sua maioria, banda larga fixa, um site de 1mb não é tão ruim, mas se for celular, é bem complicado.

Espero ter ajudado =)

Comment: Muito obrigado. Deu uma esclarecida muito boa.. É um sistema Web para desktop, embora seja responsivo. Mas o motivo de eu ter colocado todo conteúdo do sistema em um único html eh justamente a experiência do usuário, pois o sistema fica mais usual e evito aqueles refrehs na tela. Aí por isso fiquei meio temeroso em juntar tudo.

Answer (score 0):

Carregar todos os componentes e scripts em um arquivo só pode prejudicar bastante o desempenho do seu site para o cliente, uma vez que para cada request ele terá que baixar todo o conteúdo de toda a aplicação e não somente o conteúdo específico da página. Nesse [link](http://blog.caelum.com.br/por-uma-web-mais-rapida-26-tecnicas-de-otimizacao-de-sites/?utm_source=Apostila_HTML&utm_campaign=WD-43&utm_medium=referral) tem algumas dicas de perfomance web.

Comment: Entendi. Vou dar uma lida. Valeu